# If $x=A\sin\theta$ and $y=B\tan\theta$, prove this.

Tags: trigonometry

I am not good at maths it might be easy for you all.

If  $$x=A\sinθ$$  and  $$y=B\tanθ$$

Show that $$\frac{A^2}{x^2}-\frac{B^2}{y^2}=1$$

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{A}{x}=\frac{1}{\sin\theta}=\operatorname{cosec}\theta$$

and $$\frac{B}{y}=\frac{1}{\tan\theta}=\cot\theta$$

Now **square both sides** of the equation and use the fact that $$\operatorname{cosec}^2\theta-\cot^2\theta=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Just substitute!

$$\frac{A^2}{A^2\sin^2\theta} - \frac{B^2}{B^2\tan^2\theta}$$

$$\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta} - \frac{\cos^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta}$$

Unify the denominators:

$$\frac{1 - \cos^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta} = \frac{\sin^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta} = 1$$

Where I used the definition of the tangent: $\tan\theta = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$ and the identity $1 - \cos^2\theta = \sin^2\theta$.